# Spring data JPA JPQL query on child property

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data jpa. When querying parent object with child object property,I was expecting parent with aggregated child objects.I have OneToMany relation between User and Phone. Just typing some part of code.

```
@Query(select u from User u inner join u.phone ph where ph.active=:active)
Page<User> getAllUsers(@Param("active") int active);

@Entity
User{  
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  List<Phone> phone;
}

@Entity
Phone{
  @ManyToOne
  User user;
}
```

My query returns multiple User object based on active phone quantity. I was expecting one User object and all aggregated phone object in the list as part of User object. Is my assumption is wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add `DISTINCT`: `Select distinct u from User u ...` ?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj, thanks that solved multiple object problem, now I have only one. I wonder if this is workaround or is the real solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
@Query(select distinct u from User u inner join u.phone ph where ph.active=:active)
Page<User> getAllUsers(@Param("active") int active);
```

Comment: and if I want the `phone`s pre-fetched?

Comment: Then i would use JPA `EntityGraph`'s through Spring Data JPA `@EntityGraph` annotation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.html